# can't rebase master in test-branch

Tags: git, github

the issue is quiet simple, but I can't find a solution.

I have two branches : `master` and `test-branch`

`test-branch` is [`master` + one extra commit]

when I do

```
git checkout test-branch
git rebase master
```

but it returns :

```
Current branch test-branch is up to date.
```

while I am sure they aren't the same. what can I do the fix it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's already up to date so rebasing won't change something

Comment: that's the point, it's not up to date and it is saying so

Comment: Does test branch should be exact the same as master?

Comment: "master + one extra commit" sounds up to date to me. I guess you have a different expectation?

Comment: I need my master to be [current master + one extra commit] which is test-branch.

Comment: Git is telling you that this is already the situation you have. When you do `git log --all --graph --oneline`, you should see the graph of commits, including `master` as one of the parents of `test-branch`. Could it be that your `master` is itself not up-to-date with `origin/master`, and maybe that's what you're really wanting to rebase onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need my master to be [current master + one extra commit] which is test-branch.

There are multiple ways to do so. No need for rebase.

Or locally:

```
git checkout master
git merge test-branch
git push
```

Or
Push your test-branch and create a pull request to master. Then you could review the changes and run a build before merging.  See https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request

### rebase

Rebase means (in sloppy explaintion) change current branch of from which branch (or commit) it was made of and apply all new commits.

So in your question you're rebasing (and thus trying to change) test-branch

You could rebase master, but that will change the git history of master which isn't advised.

Comment: can you please explain why rebase isn't working?

Comment: Done! Let me know when things aren't clear @Bashir

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout test-branch
git rebase master
```

Comment: can you explain more what each command will do

Comment: Perhaps you have a not updated master locally. So, you have to pull changes from remote master. You can do this with command ```git pull origin master```. Other commands are familiar, I think.

Btw, if you just would like to merge changes from master to test-branch you can do it using this ```git merge master``` from test-branch.

Comment: it is already updated, I started with cloning the repo and I didn't touch master branch on local. (and to update the branch, isn't the same with `git fetch` ?)

Comment: ```git pull``` = ```git fetch``` + ```git merge```. If you do ```git fetch``` you get changes locally but not merged.

Comment: If you simply need to merge changes why don't you want to use ```get merge``` command?

Comment: `git fetch` didn't return anything, so I guess because it is already updated

Comment: Try to do what I've written in the answer above.

Comment: `git pull` return Already up to date. as I already said.